# Angular2 Looping through dynamic columns

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm building a dynamic table using angular2 using *ngFor as below, but I'm not able to see data. I'm not sure {{x[col]}} is correct, any idea?

```
<tr *ngFor="let x of exportList">
     <td *ngFor="let col of cols">
        {{x[col]}}
     </td>                      
 </tr>
```

Comment: what does your data format look like?

Comment: Check this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42633381/additional-column-created-using-angular2-and-bootstrap-4-table/42634574#42634574)

Answer (score 0):

You need to traverse each row in the inner loop.
Try:

```
<tr *ngFor="let rows of exportList">
     <td *ngFor="let col of rows">
        {{col}}
     </td>                      
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr *ngFor="let x of exportList">
     <td *ngFor="let col of x">
        {{col}}
     </td>                      
 </tr>
```

you simply need to replace cols with x. exportList contains numbers of object.so in x you will get one object in each loop.By using object,you can fetch each field.